# Ajax для увеличения показателя общего количества товаров в корзине

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, cart

У меня есть корзина, в которой добавления товара осуществлено через `ajax`. Все работает, только я не знаю как правильно обновлять через ajax общее количество товаров в корзине. Я не использую `input` с полем для ввода количества товара, мне просто нужно чтобы при каждом клике "Добавить в корзину" общее количество товаров, которое отображается в header, ajax'сом увеличивалось на 1.

Как это можно реализовать?

CartController:

```
  public function addCart(Request $request, $id){
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : NULL;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->add($product, $product->id);

    $request = Session::put('cart', $cart);

    Session::flash('add-product', $product->name);

    return redirect()->back();
  }
```

Кастомный класс Cart, где реализована основная логика добавления в корзину.

```
public function add($item, $id){
      $storedItem = [
        'qty' => 0,
        'id' => $item->id,
        'prod_url' => $item->url,
        'code_cat' => $item->category->code,
        'url_cat' => $item->category->url,
        'name' => $item->name,
        'cost' => $item->price,
        'price' => $item->price,
        'img' => $item->cardImage->path
      ];
      if($this->items){
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
          $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
        }
      }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['cost'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
```

Кнопка "В коризну":

```
<div class="product-icon-container">
  <a href="{{ route('basket-add', [ 'id' => $item->id ]) }}" class="scrollOffset btn btn-success mt-2 mb-1">Добавить в корзину</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mt-2 mb-1">Купить сейчас!</a>
</div>
```

Собственно, то место, где должно выводиться общее количество товаров:

```
<span class="prodcount">{{ Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : '0' }}</span><i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i><span class="basket-text">Cart</span>
```

Простой ajax запрос, который добавляет товар в корзину:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.product-icon-container').find('a.scrollOffset').click(function (event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('href')
   });
  return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

**CartController**

```php
public function addCart(Request $request, $id){
  $product = Product::find($id);
  $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : NULL;
  $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
  $cart->add($product, $product->id);
  $request = Session::put('cart', $cart);

  Session::flash('add-product', $product->name);

  return response()->json([
      'total_quantity' => Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : '0'
  ]);
}
```

**Ajax запрос**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.product-icon-container').find('a.scrollOffset').click(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('href'),
      dataType: 'JSON',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $('.prodcount').html(response.total_quantity);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

**В header**

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

P.S. Возможно вместе с ajax запросом вам надо отправить csrf_token, если это Laravel (судя по коду)

Comment: Работает, спасибо! Я формы не использую, по этому csrf не просит или лучше все равно добавить?

Comment: Я вам написал код сразу с отправкой csrf токена.